# Rails 4: Grouping Controllers in a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to group all my controllers and their views in folders for example under "admin"

This what I did: 
(1) I moved all the `controllers` under a folder `admin`
(2) I moved all the `views` under a folder `admin`

(3) I read in Rails Guide that I should be doing this:

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :admin_permissions, :admin_layout, :admin_db
end
```

but I keep getting an error

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /admin_permissions/index
uninitialized constant AdminMainController
```

Directory Structure:

```
controllers
  -> admin
    -> admin_main_controller
    -> admin_permissions_controller
    -> admin_layouts_controller
    -> admin_db_controller
views
  -> admin
    -> admin_main
    -> admin_permissions
    -> admin_layouts
    -> admin_db
```

All first three controllers inherit from admin_main which inherits from application

Any advise on what to read/check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you execute `rake routes`, you will notice the names of all your controllers is prefixed with 'admin/'.

Because you move your controllers to directory "admin", you should add a namespace to each controller there. For example:

```
class Admin::AdminMainController < ActionController::Base
end
```

And check your controllers, views and helpers, update all relevant paths and controller's names.

Comment: Thanks!! I added it everywhere, do I also include it when I import a helper? "include Admin::AdminMainHelper" or just "include AdminMainHelper"

Comment: Depend on what's the module name of your helper now. If the name is "Admin::AdminMainHelper", so "include Admin::AdminMainHelper", or "include AdminMainHelper"