# Rails Controllers in subfolder ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen related questions here in StackOverflow, but I still can't make it work.

I'm making an API with subfolders inside controllers, but I keep getting this error:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::Report::ReportController, expected ... 
/controllers/api/report/report_controller.rb to define it):
```

Or this one:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::Report::ReportController):
```

This is my folder structure:

```
->controllers
    ->api
       ->report
         infected_controller.rb
         report_controller.rb


# inflected_controller.rb
module Api
  class Report::InfectedController < ReportController
    def infected
    end
  end
end

# report_controller.rb
module Api
  class ReportController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
  end
end
```

And my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  apipie
  namespace :api do
    scope module: 'report' do
      get 'infected' => 'infected#infected'
      resources :report
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: Grouping Controllers in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264446/rails-4-grouping-controllers-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

```
module Api
  module Report # <============== missing module
    class ReportController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also

```
module Api
  class Report::InfectedController < Report::ReportController
    def infected
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still not working, ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::ReportController):

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
# report_controller.rb
module Api
  class Report::ReportController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
  end
end
```